# Storing additional values on a many-to-many relationship in KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

I have a many-to-many relationship between my `Post` and `Tag` lists and I want to record the date when a tag is added to a post. I can't see how to add this field when defining a many-to-many relationship between these lists.

Does it mean that I have to manually create a `PostTag` list that has a one-to-many relationship with the `Post` list and another one-to-many relationship with the `Tag` list?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no mechanism for adding fields to the relationship itself (although it has [come up before](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/1362#issuecomment-519381778)). The thinking being that, if you need to store additional information "on" the relationship, it stops being a pure relationship and becomes a list, with fields, like any other.

> Does it mean that I have to manually create a list `POSTTAGS` that has a O2M relationship with `POST` and another O2M relationship with `TAGS`?

Yes, this is one way of solving the problem and probably the best in most instances. The downside is that it changes the interface you'll be given for adding tags to posts; you'll now need to "create" the `PostTag` items which might be clunkier from a UX perspective.

Another potential solution would be to leave the many-to-many relation field as is and store the extra data somewhere else. For example you could add a json field to posts called `taggedDates` and use [hooks](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/hooks) to record when links are created or destroyed. Note, to make this work, you may need a hook on *both* the `Post` and `Tag` lists, as (depending on how the fields are configured) the relationship between items could be modified from either side.

The former solution is probably better most of the time but the latter does let you keep the nice many-to-many interfaces in the Admin UI, if that's what you're prioritising.

---

Bonus future solution – This doesn't help you right now but [there's been talk](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/discussions/6994) of adding an escape hatch that lets developers selectively override parts of the generated Prisma schema. It's not general solution for "fields on relationship" problem but if really all you needed was a timestamp for when the link was created, this functionality would let you do that. Unfortunately you'd need to use `context.prisma` directly to query the values and, of course, the feature doesn't actually *exist* yet (but there's a good chance it will land in the next month or two).

Comment: thks for your comment